# Collection view cell to be added in the beginning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, imageview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view cell with a imageview in it.The data fetched from server is stored in a array.I want the latest image fetched be shown in collection view cell in the beginning instead of at the end.Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please show your relevant code, and we will help! :)

Comment: -(void) getPhotservice {   
    [NewJsonHelperClass getExecuteWithParams:msgStr secondParm:nil onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){        
        NSDictionary *user =[NSDictionary new];
        user =[json valueForKey:@"user"];
        NSMutableArray *dArr =[NSMutableArray new];
        dArr =[userDict valueForKey:@"Images"];
        for (int i = 0; i <= dArr.count-1; i++)
        {  reUse =[ReuseVc new];
            reUse.photo_link = dArr[i];
            [serverData addObject:reUse];}        
        [self.colView reloadData]
    }];
}

Comment: here the serverData is being in the collection view array,so here the data which is added last should be shown in the beginning in collection view.how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have correct your code a little, no need to allocate data when your JSON class seems to give it to you. Assuming the `serverData` is of kind `NSMutableArray`, this should work. I changed `addObject:` to `insertObject:atIndex:`.

```
-(void) getPhotservice {
    [NewJsonHelperClass getExecuteWithParams:msgStr secondParm:nil onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
        NSDictionary *user = [json valueForKey:@"user"];
        NSMutableArray *dArr = [userDict valueForKey:@"Images"];
        for (int i = 0; i <= dArr.count-1; i++) {
            reUse = [ReuseVc new];
            reUse.photo_link = dArr[i];

            // Just add it to the top
            [serverData insertObject:reUse atIndex:0];
        }
        [self.colView reloadData]
    }];
}
```

Comment: so this way it will always add the new element in the beginning?

Comment: Use performBatch updates and insert at the beginning